# Tableau - creating vertical lines on specific dates when the date axis (x-axis) is set to "week"

Tags: date, tableau-api

I'm graphing weekly total page loads per 1000 students, which is easy enough when the pill for the page load variable is set to 'sum', and the date pill is set to 'week number.'

BUT, I also have a table that lists individual dates on which important policy changes occurred, and I want to draw those as vertical lines.

Using a dual axis, I have been able to plot the specific dates as lines, but because the resolution of the date axis is set to "week", it lumps all dates in the policy change table that occur within a single week into one, or possibly omits dates that don't land on the right date for that week, and therefore I don't get individual lines for every policy change.
[weekly resolution, dates omitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyqB0.png)

I have been able to approximate what I'm looking for by setting the date pill to 'day,' and then doing a rolling average of the page load values--but this doesn't represent the page loads in the way I need it to.
[rolling sum, not the same calculation, but includes dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUh8T.png)

I need either a way to layer two charts on top of each other, with different x-axis resolutions, or possibly the correct calculated field that gives me the straight up weekly sum of the daily total page loads for successive weeks, so I can use the 'day' setting on the date-time access but still get the weekly values I want, and then plot all dates in the policy change table.

Comment: So in your weekly view, the "Schools Close" mark is not omitted. It's just on the same line as "Ev Proceedings". If you go into the Text marks card and check "Allow Labels to Overlap Other Marks", you should see both labels. You could create a measure that you map to Size, which would make both lines visible, as long as the bottom line is larger than the top line. That's all if you stick with weeks on the columns shelf.

Comment: If you prefer a daily view, it's unclear to me what your desired calculation for page loads is.

Comment: Maybe `{FIXED WEEK(Time): sum(Engagement)}` to get a weekly total that repeats for each day

Comment: I don't prefer a daily view--I prefer the weekly view, BUT, with a weekly view, I cannot plot lines for dates of COVID policy changes that do not fall on the date of the weekly aggregation.

Comment: Mako212--thank you for the suggestion--using FIXED doesn't allow me to filter the view by all the different measures, but I will tinker with that--I'm not at all up on LOD expressions, and really want to get up to speed on them!

Comment: you might need to check "Add to Context" on the filters you want to use, if you're using LODs